How to get the values from a list that are not in a particular column of a table in Database
I am using Spring Boot 3, Java 17 and mariaDB.
I have a list nameList = {"alice", "bob", " john", "tom"}. In DB, I also have a table T with two columns a, b. The table looks like below.



a
b




alice
30


bob
50


mike
20


zia
10



I want to search on column a with nameList, that will provide me the names from the nameList that are not in column a.
The expected result would be a list
result = {"john", "tom"}
I am unable to write the correct JPQL.
Please note, I don't want to do post manipulation. For example, by writing select t.a from T t where t.a in :nameList, I found at first {"alice", "bob"}, then excluding it from nameList (post processing), I can get the expected output. I want the query take care of everything.

Did you try this: select t.a from T t where t.a NOT in :nameList  ? I think that just negating the condition would do the trick

@pochopsp, isn’t it supposed to produce {"mike", "zia"}? If so, then it is not my expected result. Expected result would be {"john", "tom"}.

You're right, I misinterpreted your question

See LEFT JOIN...WHERE id IS NULL.

This is best done by finding the rows that are in the list, then in your client excluding those from the list.
I don't know what JPQL can do, but if you had to do it in mariadb you'd do:
select searching.a
from ((select a from T limit 0) union all (values ('alice'),('bob'),('john'),('tom'))) searching
where not exists (select 1 from T where T.a=searching.a)

The (select a from T limit 0) just provides a name and type for the subquery result column; mariadb and mysql provide default column names from the values table constructor, but they differ between the two and mariadb's in particular are not helpful.
In mysql, the values table constructor requires ROW before each row value:
select searching.a
from ((select a from T limit 0) union all (values row('alice'),row('bob'),row('john'),row('tom'))) searching
where not exists (select 1 from T where T.a=searching.a)

fiddle
